# Using keypoints to compute object similarity

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-recognition

I'm not sure, but can I use keypoints of an image for object recognition? I have MATLAB implementation of Harris keypoint extraction. Its output is an array of points, I don't know how can I use these points (the number of points in Harris algorithm vary) for recognizing purpose. There is another method, LoG (Laplace of Gaussian) that produce 120x3 for each image.
Keypoints example:[image]

It's my objects dataset: http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/datasets/downloads/Obj_DB.tar.gz , images background is white, as seen in the above image. What I want is training a Neural Network with a train set (some of those pictures) and then test the Neural Network with remained pictures. 

If it's not clear I can provide more info.

Comment: It seems like your problem is that some operation needs to be performed on matrices of different sizes. Could you provide more detail on the operations you need to perform in Matlab?

Comment: No in fact, the output of these keypoint extraction algorithms are pixels position, pure pixel position is useless, I have to extract some features of these positions.

Comment: since the position of the object varies, there will obviously not be a one-one correspondence between the positions of the corners detected for the two images. So (just musing at random) you might take, say, a 20x20 neighborhood of each corner point of one image and compute the avg greyvalue (or into RBG separately) of each neighborhood. take 10 bins and accordingly make a histogram of these color values. Do the same for the 2nd image (calculate avg greyvalue for each corner's neighborhood - getting one value for each of the `n` detected corners, then group these n values into 10 bins again)

Comment: compare the two histograms, most easily by taking the ratio of each bin of 1st and 2nd image. If the 10 resulting ratios are close to unity then the color distribution at the corner points are similar.

Comment: Thank you AruniRC. It's good idea, but how can I feed a Neural Network with various number of inputs? if I use Harris method, the number of points vary in different pictures.

Comment: Is the neural network a must? Otherwise I might know a direction or two one could try

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider SIFT algorithm?
It compute a unique (Scale and orientation invariant) signature for each "corner" using a variable sized neighborhood. afterwards the signatures can be matched using nearest neighbor (L2 norm).